# ADB can't find my Samsung galaxy S4

Tags: android, adb, device

For some reason ADB can't find my S4 although I'm the opinion that I've done everything:
-Added my hardware id to android_winusb and adb_usb
-Enabled USB-debugging
-Changed USB ports
-Rebooted several times
-Installed Kies
-Installed google driver via driver manager

My OS: Win 7 x64
Additionally: the device manager shows my mobile twice: once in 'Other devices' as SAMSUNG_Android and once as [hostname] in 'Portable devices'

Have i forgotten something?

New information:
Now I know that the issue has to do with my pc software configuration.

Comment: this should help you to determine whether you have a problem with your PC or your phone http://ktnr74.blogspot.com/2014/11/adb-device-detection-in-windows.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Samsung universal adb driver
http://download.clockworkmod.com/test/UniversalAdbDriverSetup6.msi

Sometimes you just need to deactivate and reactivate USB debugging to work too.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem before. This is what helped me:

1. Remove phone drivers from pc
2. Remove usb cable and reconnect
3. Reinstall phone drivers

Hope this helps...

Comment: It doesn't help. I have tried another computer and got the same results.